# Function conserving volume: Cannot see that $\text{vol}(U)=\text{vol}(g^n(U))~~~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: analysis

I am a little bit confused!

I know it that way: A function $g\colon M\to M$ is called to conserve volume if for all Jordan-measurable sets $J\subset M$ it is $\text{vol}(g^{-1}(J))=\text{vol}(J)$.

Now the following setting:

> > Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be Jordan-measurable and $g\colon M\to M$ bijective, continious and coserving volume which inverse is continious. Let $U\subset M$ Jordan-measurable.

In a book I found this setting and then saying that
$$
\text{vol}(U)=\text{vol}(g^n(U))~~~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$

I cannot understand this identity! Do you and can you explain that to me? I only see that
$$
\text{vol}(U)=\text{vol}(g^{-n}(U))~~~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $U=g^{-n}(V)$ for some $V\subset M$. Note that every $U$ is of this form since $g^{n}$ is bijective and $g^{n}(g^{-n}(V))=V$.
Now, using that the equality $\text{vol}(A)=\text{vol}(g^{-n}(A))$ is valid for every $A\subset M$, then, setting $A=g^n(U)=V$ we have
$$
\text{vol}(g^n(U))=\text{vol}(A)=\text{vol}(g^{-n}(A))=\text{vol}(g^{-n}(g^n(U)))=\text{vol}(U)
$$
Which is the desired equality.

Comment: Did not get it completely. Because $g$ conserves volume it is $\text{vol}(g^{-n}(U))=\text{vol}(U)$. Furthermore it is $g^{-n}(U)=g^{-n}(g^n(V))=V$ for a $V\subset M$. Why now is $\text{vol}(g^n(U))=\text{vol}(U)$?

Comment: Because I can change the roles of $U$ and $V$, i.e. there is a $V$ with $V=g^n(U)$ and then $\text{vol}(g^{-n}(V))=\text{vol}(U)=\text{vol}(V)=\text{vol}(g^n(U))$?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer to clarify.